# Adding a Google+ registration method to an application with an existing user database

Tags: php, google-plus, registration

Would anyone be kind enough to help me with the logic of adding Google registration to my app. I understand the technical side (retrieving the data etc.) but I'm a bit stumped as to how to actually save that information. I currently have an email/password system for registration and the user table in my database contains the name, email, password and avatar of the user.

What would be the best way to save a user with the data retrieved from G+? 
Would I have a separate table?
Would I add it to the the same table, perhaps with a generated prefix for the password?
If I did that how would I prevent login from the regular email/password form for that user?

Any insight into how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would be having a unique id for each user.What you can do is create a separate table for g+ data.Add a column of g_username in current table When user has authenticated add information to your g+ table, with unique id as his g_username.

When user will try to login using g+ you can lookup that g+ id and if user uses uses his password you can check g+ column value for empty or null.

Comment: Alright, I assumed I would probably need a second table. This leads me to a few issues, searching for users in multiple tables and other nested queries. Would I just have to deal with the multiple tables or would you suggest creating a ghost user in the original user table based on the g_username. Thanks for the answer and the edit btw. :)

Comment: There is another answer. You can add a column. in your table Add the json_encoded data in table that would be not increase overhead of sql queries.